# I'm having trouble understanding Hensel's lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I don't know if either I didn't quite get the lemma or the problem has an elegant solution. So, I got this problem from a friend, and the hint was to use Hensel's lemma, which I didn't know and searched in Wikipedia, I couldn't see how to use it and solved it in other way.

What I understood of the lemma is that it says if $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $a$ is such that $f(a)\equiv_p0$ for some prime $p$ then $a$ is a unique root for the same equation modulo $p^k$.

The problem was to solve

$$2^x=3^y+17$$

over the integers. But I don't see any polynomial I could use

Comment: @ALG but doesn't $f$ have to be a polynomial?

Comment: no need. if $y$ is even then $3^y + 17 \equiv 2 \pmod 8.$   if $y$ is odd then $3^y + 17 \equiv 4 \pmod 8.$

Comment: @BrunoAndrades In fact Hensel lemma works with analytic functions over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and $2^x-3^y+17$ is analytic in $x$ (why ?)

Answer (score 0):

Since $2\equiv 3^{14}\pmod{17}$, we have
$3^{14x}\equiv 3^y\pmod{17}$, hence $y\equiv 14x\pmod{16}$ from which $y\equiv 2x\pmod 4$.
Reducing modulo $5$ gives $3^y\equiv 3^{2x}\equiv 4^x\pmod 5$, hence $2^x\equiv 4^x+2\pmod 5$ which is impossible for $x\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ hence impossible for all $x\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: But I want to know how to use hensel's lemma, or even if I got it, I already have a solution to this problem